# How do I use the if / then command in python

Tags: python, if-statement, pyautogui

So very recently, I have started learning python, and I have come up with a very basic script that should ask the user a question, and move the cursor to a spot on the screen based on the answer that the program receives. But when I run the program it runs the first part of the code, then closes the interpreter as if the program was finished.

```
import pyautogui
import time
choice = 0
choice = pyautogui.prompt("Which option do you choose? ")
                                                                   # The code stops working here
if choice == 1:
    pyautogui.moveTo(670, 440)
elif choice == 2:
    pyautogui.moveTo(690, 440)
elif choice == 3:
    pyautogui.moveTo(670, 500)
elif choice == 4:
    pyautogui.moveTo(690, 500)
```

I believe that the issue is with the if / then command but is could be something as simple as an indention error.

I apologise in advance for any formatting mistakes that I made when typing up this question as I am quite new to stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to elaborate on top of @zerecees's already excellent answer to account for possible edge cases that might break down your program.

```py
import time
import pyautogui

while True:
   try:
      choice = int(pyautogui.prompt("Which option do you choose? "))
      break
   except ValueError:
      print("Please type an integer value.")

if choice == 1:
    pyautogui.moveTo(670, 440)
elif choice == 2:
    pyautogui.moveTo(690, 440)
elif choice == 3:
    pyautogui.moveTo(670, 500)
elif choice == 4:
    pyautogui.moveTo(690, 500)
else:
    # Some default fallback code
```

The `try` and `except` statement accounts for cases in which the user inputs something that cannot be casted into `int`. For example, imagine a situation where the user inputs `one` instead of `1`; in such cases, type conversion will not work. Therefore, we use a `while` loop to prompt the user to input a valid input until a valid input is entered.

Then, since we have converted the input from a string to an integer, the conditionals will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`pyautogui.prompt()` returns a `string`, and you are checking for `int`. Try putting quotes around `if .. "1", elif .. "2"` to make the `int`'s `string`'s.

Or, try:

`int(pyautogui.prompt("...")` to convert `string` to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is `pyautogui.prompt()` is returning a string and you are checking for integer. You can check the return type using,

> print(type(choice))

So change the type. If you still get stuck(if you didn't get the prompt window) then there may be some security issues, so you will need to explicitly allow application to use mouse/keyboard. Just have a look at accessibility in security preference and allow the appropriate action. Hope this will help :)